# Using Koszul complex

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, homological-algebra

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $t$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. If $J\subset A$ is an $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal then we have
>    the following complex for $n\in \Bbb N$:
>   $$0\to \frac{A}{J^{n-t}}\to (\frac{A}{J^{n-t+1}})^t\to(\frac{A}{J^{n-t+2}})^{\binom{t}{2}}\to\cdots\to \frac{A}{J^n}\to 0.$$

How can we use the Koszul complex to achieve this complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex you mentioned is called the *modified Koszul complex*, and appears in the paper *[Hilbert coefficients and the depths of associated graded rings](http://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/hilbfinal.pdf)* by Huckaba and Marley. Let me briefly mention its relation to the Koszul complex.

Let's denote the given complex by $C(n,J)$, and let $x_1,\dots,x_t\in J$. Then there is an exact sequence of complexes
$$0\to K(n,J)\to K(x_1,\dots,x_t)\to C(n,J)\to 0,$$ 
where $K(n,J)$ is the subcomplex of $K(x_1,\dots,x_t)$ given by
$$0\to J^{n-t}\to(J^{n-t+1})^t\to(J^{n-t+2})^{\binom{t}{2}}\to\cdots\to J^n\to 0.$$